# How are permissions on default administrative shares controlled?

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

The ACEs on our default administrative shares (C$, D$ etc.) suggest that the Users group has read/write access to the disk roots. In practice though it appears that only Domain Admins group can actually open these shares at the root.

How are the effective permissions controlled and why is it set up this way?  Is it to establish explicit permissions for inheritance purposes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the NTFS ACLs on those items are permissive, the share ACLs on these default system shares are always set to allow just the local `Administrators` group (which contains the `Domain Admins` group).

The permissions on these items cannot be modified.

Comment: Thanks - any idea where this is documented?  It would be useful to know because it looks contradictory unless one knows that the permissions are baked in.

Comment: @zen All file shares have two ACLs that govern access; the NTFS ACL and the file share ACL; you'll run into these seemingly contradictory situations often unless you check both.  These special file shares' ACLs behave the same way, they're just also hidden.

Answer (score 7):

The permissions for those default admin shares are hard coded in Windows and can't be changed (at least not successfully).